# Linear Layout not visible

Tags: android, layout

In the following piece of code the Linear Layout at the extreme bottom is not visible.I tried several methods but couldn't make it visible.Please take a look

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/GlobalBG"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/id_nav_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_nav_layout" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/id_home_screen_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_linear_layout_system_capacity"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dip"
        android:background="@drawable/home_storage_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Dummy"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/id_linear_layout_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/home_seekbar_bg" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/home_bottom_bg"/ >
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have put

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

as wrap_content and there is no content inside your layout so it is not visible maybe

Comment: That is not the case..the layout will be visible if there is a BG.

Comment: I tried it
set the height of TextView as wrap_content or any minimal height instead of fill_parent

this works

Comment: @Hari...Yes that helps...But it hides the text in the text view...
Any clue how to adjust that?

Comment: hmmm set padding as 10dp or more for TextView as per your requirement

Comment: I adjusted the margin so as to align the text...Thus the bug has been fixed.. Thank you Hari..

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by editing the code as below:-

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Dummy"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score -1):

As I understand this invisible layout should be always visible in the bottom of the screen, then you should better use `RelativeLayout` insted of `LinearLayout`
Change this layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/GlobalBG"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

TO `<RelativeLayout>` and set this `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to your invisible layout

Edited:
this works for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/red" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/id_linear_layout_system_capacity"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="105dip"
    android:background="@color/row_base_background_end"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Dummy"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_linear_layout_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/row_base_background_start" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/gray" >
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```